# How to resolve "error loading libxml2.so.2" when installing Cisco AnyConnect VPN?

Tags: vpn, shared-library, cisco

I'm trying to install Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client on Maverick 64-bit. I'm getting the following errors:

```
Installing Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client ...
Removing previous installation...
/opt/cisco/vpn/bin/manifesttool: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
vpnagentd: no process found
Extracting installation files to /tmp/vpn.Mjh9Z5/vpninst086037244.tgz...
Unarchiving installation files to /tmp/vpn.Mjh9Z5...
Starting the VPN agent...
/opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpnagentd: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have libxml2.so.2 in /usr/lib, though. Should it be somewhere else?

Thanks in advance.